# Diet drugs mailed out?

Tags: harassment

I received 2-90 day packages of diet pills in the mail. They were not ordered by me. I was not charged (yet) but the packing slip showed $104.50 as cost. There was an account set up with this company using my name.

I have some serious medical conditions. I am being monitored by specialists to not do damage to my kidneys. I am obese and need to lose weight. I am also working with specialist on weight management. Is it legal for someone else to purchase diet drugs and send to another person?
I live in SD.  The diet pills are manufactured exclusively for B EPIC.  The name on the package is ACCELER8.
Will it affect my kidneys, yes.  My calcium and calcium citrate levels are being monitored.  These pills contain Magnesium Citrate, Calcium Citrate.  There are a lot of different kinds of roots, bark, extracts, Hops, Melatonin.

Comment: Ok, what type of diet pills are these? Are they over the counter? Is there an age limit on them? Are the diet pills going to cause harm to your kidneys? Please add a little more information about the drug, and organize the relevancy of the current information.

Comment: In what jurisdiction are you locaed? Mostly what country, as such laws are generally national.

Comment: Are you sure this isn’t a scam where they send you cheap supplements and then send letters demanding you pay some large amount of money?

Answer (score 2):

It depends in part on what the substance is, and who sent it. If it is overpriced herbs, anyone can send you herbs in the mail. If this is a prescription drug, one must be an entity registered with the DEA, to mail drugs. If this was sent by one of the large pharma companies, it is likely legal for them to mail it,but it has to be sent to the person who the prescription is for. Also note that if you don't have a prescription for a prescription drug, it is not legal to possess the drug. However, you might unknowingly have a prescription, it a physician prescribed it for you without telling you, or seeing you (it happens).

The stuff you describe is not prescription and it is legal to send and have it. It is probably risky to take it, so just don't pay for it if they bill you. Things sent to you unsolicited can be legally treated as a gift.